# How do I get the path to the currently selected file

Tags: vbscript, selection, explorer, livecode

Does VBScript have a function to get the path to the currently selected file in File Explorer? If so, what is the function? I'm looking for something like

```
Set fileObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
dim filepath 
filepath = fileObj.GetCurrentSelection() 'doesn´t exist
dim result
result = filepath 'communicate with LiveCode
```

Comment: No, it doesn't. Depending on what you actually want to achieve you could add a context menu entry that calls a VBScript with the path of the selected object. You may get better answers if you explained what you need this for.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I would like to add some scripting capabilities to my existing software and allow for getting information about the currently selected file, duplicating the selected file, and other basic operations. I'll think about using a contextual menu.

Comment: If you have selected the file/folder using Browse Folder, then it is easy to get the selected file.

Comment: @Pankaj you misunderstood the question. Your comment is confusing to future readers.

Comment: Apparently so ... my bad.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg314982(v=vs.85).aspx could be helpful

Comment: Why do you need to speak to Windows explorer to get the selected file into your application? Why don't you use your existing application to have the user select a file? Or, have your application register a shell extension the way something like Winzip does. VBS isn't really capable or suitable for what you're talking about doing...

Comment: @Jobo because the user wants to be able to select a file in File Explorer and do something with it.

Comment: Anyone having an idea to resolve the error or perhaps a different approach?

Answer (score 6):

I wrote a simple example.
Keep in mind there may be more than one open windows explorer window and this will list them all.

```vb
Function GetSelectedFiles() 'Returns paths as array of strings
    Dim FileList, Window, SelectedItem
    'avoid duplicates by storing paths in dictionary keys
    Set FileList = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With CreateObject("Shell.Application")
        For Each Window In .Windows
            'skip IE Windows
            If InStr(1, Window.FullName, "iexplore.exe", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                For Each SelectedItem In Window.Document.SelectedItems
                    FileList(SelectedItem.Path) = Null
                Next
            End If
        Next
    End With

    GetSelectedFiles = FileList.Keys 'array of paths
End Function

MsgBox  "Click OK after selecting the items",  _
        vbOKOnly Or vbInformation, "Select a few items"

Dim SelectedFiles
    SelectedFiles =  GetSelectedFiles

MsgBox  "You selected: " & vbNewLine  & vbNewLine & _
         Join(SelectedFiles, vbNewLine), vbOKOnly Or vbInformation, "Selected Items"

'loop through array
'Dim FileItem
'For Each FileItem In SelectedFiles
'   WScript.Echo FileItem
'Next
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to try this. I'll get back to you.

Comment: I get the following error:
`Script: C\Users\USER\Desktop\path.vbs, 
Line: 10, 
Char: 17, 
Error: Object doesn't support this property or method: 'Windows.Document.SelectedItems', 
Code: 800A01B6, 
Source: Microsoft VBScript runtime error`.  This is on Windows 8. I can't give you the bounty yet, but it is definitely an interesting script.

Comment: @Mark I should say I've never used this kind of script before, investigated for you. Frankly I don't know what causes the error under which circumstances. Just I can say that the iterated Document object has no SelectedItems method, but I don't know why yet. I tested the scipt only on Windows 2008 R2 (x64), Windows 2008 x86, Windows 8.1 Pro x64 (my dev pc) and Windows 8 Pro x86 with no errors. Apparently it's not enough. I'll try reproduce the error in my spare time. Maybe you can tell what kind of Windows or Internet Explorer instances were open while script working. It may helpful.

Comment: I have one or two desktop windows open. This is Windows File Explorer, not Internet Explorer. I don't use Pro.

Comment: @Mark Of course it is not IE but Windows Explorer and IE shares same engine. So you can see that, there is an If condition to eliminate IE instances in the code. Just asked for that. Well, what edition you're using now. Home Premium, Home Basic or Starter (aka Bloody) Edition? I'll try to debug script in a virtual machine if necessary. And how about trying to run script after replacing the comment line `'skip IE Windows` with `On Error Resume Next`? Could you try it.

Comment: Funny. The only clue about the edition of Windows I have is the possibility to upgrade to Pro. Nowhere I can find a reference to the edition I am currently using. In the System control panel, it just says "Windows 8.1 (c) Microsoft Coporation, Get more features...".

Comment: @Mark You can learn which edition you're on running `winver.exe` through `Win + R` keystroke.

Comment: I know about that. I just says Windows 8, Microsoft Windows Version 6.4 (Build 9600), (c) 2013... etc. No mention of an edition.

Comment: It just says: "The Windows 8.1 operating system and..." :-)

Comment: Anyone having an idea to resolve the error or perhaps a different approach?

Comment: @Mark I even tried on Windows XP SP1 (12 years old OS) and it works, have a look at : http://i.imgur.com/BVcawLm.png
My only guess is that the edition of Windows you're on does not support the interface(s) used in the script. 
I don't know, it is Starter or a kind of Preview edition so you know we were unable to determine. Unfortunately I have no any other suggestion or solution. Sorry.

Comment: I guess this isn't going to be solved but hopefully your answer will eventually show me the way to a solution. I guess I should give you the reward.

Comment: Where is this `Document.SelectedItems` interface documented? I tried it and it really works, but I can't find documentation for it.

Comment: @GetFree hey, it's here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774049%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

try this by this you can get the path to the currently selected file.you also need to

```
Set objFS=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
    strFile= objArgs(0)
    Set objFile = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFile)
    Set objFile = objFS.GetFile(strFile)
    WScript.Echo objFile.Path
```

Comment: Error: Subscript out of range, Code: 800A0009, Source: Microsoft VBScript runtime error, line 3, char 4.

Comment: and the command is c:\test> cscript //nologo myscript.vbs myfile